# using window.open with knockout binding

Tags: arrays, knockout.js, foreach, onclick

I'm using knockout's `foreach` loop that fetches the values from an array and displays it in a href tag.

This all works well but once I use javascript's `onclick` (I need this onclick as I am using InAppBrowser plugin for mobiles) and uses the variables inside it, it doesn't work. See example here:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: consumerData" style="margin-bottom:100px;">  
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<p style="font-size:larger; margin-bottom:5px;">
<a style="text-decoration:none;" 
data-bind="attr: { href: 'http://domain:8080/dsservlet/'+$data[0]+'.png?key=DK188961' }, 
text: $data[1]" target="_blank" 
onclick="window.open('http://domain:8080/dsservlet/'+$data[0]+'.png?key=DK188961', 
'_blank', 'location=yes'); return false;"></a></p>
</td></tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

As you can see the `$data[0]` works fine inside the data-bind attribute. But using the same `$data[0]` inside the onclick doesn't work which is still inside the foreach loop. I assume I need to declare a javascript variable to be able to make it work, but how do I declare it inside the foreach loop? I need to declare it inside the foreach loop as the array varies with different values.

See the javscript part here:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  this.consumerData = ko.observableArray([[174302,"BUSINESS - APPLICATION TO CONDUCT A BUSINESS FROM HOME.pdf",".pdf","DK89639"],[120183,"Glovent-Brochure.pdf",".pdf","DK472894"]]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Knockout there's a [different way to handle `onclick`: use a `click` binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html). Like this:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.consumerData = ko.observableArray([[174302,"BUSINESS - APPLICATION TO CONDUCT A BUSINESS FROM HOME.pdf",".pdf","DK89639"],[120183,"Glovent-Brochure.pdf",".pdf","DK472894"]]);

    this.openServlet = function(data) {
        window.open('http://domain:8080/dsservlet/'+data[0]+'.png?key=DK188961', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<a data-bind="attr: { href: 'http://domain:8080/dsservlet/'+$data[0]+'.png?key=DK188961' },
              click: $parent.openServlet 
              text: $data[1]" 
   target="_blank"></a>
```

Please read linked documentation carefully, it'll have the answers to many follow-up questions that might arise.

Finally, consider converting `consumerData` to a proper sub view model in its own right, instead of a raw array of data. This would allow you to create the `href` in an observable or computed observable, thus also allowing you to unit test it.

As a footnote, if you *really* need to have an `onclick` you could set it using the `attr` binding you also used for `href`. So for example:

```js
var ConsumerData = function(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = data[0];
  self.filename = data[1];
  self.extension = data[2];
  self.code = data[3];

  self.url = 'http://domain:8080/dsservlet/' + self.id + '.png?key=DK188961';

  self.openServlet = function() {
    window.open(self.url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
  };

  self.onclickValue = "window.open('http://domain:8080/dsservlet/'+data[0]+'.png?key=DK188961', '_blank', 'location=yes'); return false";

  // Overwrite them again for testing on StackOverflow (window.open is crap for testing)
  self.openServlet = function() { alert(self.url); };
  self.onclickValue = "alert('" + self.url + "'); return false;";
};

var ViewModel = function() {
  this.consumers = ko.observableArray([
    new ConsumerData([174302, "BUSINESS - APPLICATION TO CONDUCT A BUSINESS FROM HOME.pdf", ".pdf", "DK89639"]),
    new ConsumerData([120183, "Glovent-Brochure.pdf", ".pdf", "DK472894"])
  ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: consumers">
  <p>
    <a data-bind="attr: { href: url, onclick: onclickValue }, click: openServlet, text: filename" target="_blank"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! It's almost working. In a browser it works but in the mobile app it doesn't because the InAppBrowser plugin is expecting an onclick inside the a attribute. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: If you *have to* use `onclick` then you could always set it using `attr` bindings. See final example.